# ng2-pdf-viewer problems with render more than one PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, angular5, pdf-viewer

I'm trying to view pdf using ng2-pdf-viewer in my angular6 project, but I'm not able to render more than one pdf.

It shows only one pdf file and all other shows only loading gif

```
<div class="pdf-container" *ngFor="let item of pdfURLS">                                                              
  <pdf-viewer id="item.src" [src]="item.src" [original-size]="false">                                                                
  </pdf-viewer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: <div class="pdf-container" *ngFor="let item of pdfURLS">                                                              
      <pdf-viewer id="item.src" [src]="item.src" [original-size]="false">                                                                
      </pdf-viewer>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Iterating pdf-viewer tag like this multiple times will create multiple instances of pdf-viewer that could even cause memory leak as pdf.js used by pdf-viewer does not optimally handle memory leaks.